# combining two arrays data on same id in php

Tags: php

hello i have this type of array,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00092
            [splcode] => FGC00092
            [1] => 2016-05-02,2016-05-09
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-02,2016-05-09
            [2] => 3,40
            [unit] => 3,40
            [3] => 300,320
            [value] => 300,320
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00085
            [splcode] => FGC00085
            [1] => 2016-05-06
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-06
            [2] => 2
            [unit] => 2
            [3] => 400
            [value] => 400
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00099
            [splcode] => FGC00099
            [1] => 2016-05-06
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-06
            [2] => 3
            [unit] => 3
            [3] => 600
            [value] => 600
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00092
            [splcode] => FGC00092
            [1] => 2016-05-09
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-09
            [2] => 40
            [unit] => 40
            [3] => 320
            [value] => 320
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00115
            [splcode] => FGC00115
            [1] => 2016-05-10
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-10
            [2] => 476
            [unit] => 476
            [3] => 3808
            [value] => 3808
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00062
            [splcode] => FGC00062
            [1] => 2016-05-25
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-25
            [2] => 10
            [unit] => 10
            [3] => 80
            [value] => 80
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00059
            [splcode] => FGC00059
            [1] => 2016-05-30
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-30
            [2] => 50
            [unit] => 50
            [3] => 400
            [value] => 400
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00117
            [splcode] => FGC00117
            [1] => 2016-05-31
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-31
            [2] => 50
            [unit] => 50
            [3] => 400
            [value] => 400
        )

)
```

i want to combine the them which have same ID. like for FGC00092, array structure must be,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00092
            [splcode] => FGC00092
            [1] => 2016-05-02
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-02
            [2] => 3
            [unit] => 3
            [3] => 300
            [value] => 300
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00085
            [splcode] => FGC00085
            [1] => 2016-05-06
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-06
            [2] => 2
            [unit] => 2
            [3] => 400
            [value] => 400
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00099
            [splcode] => FGC00099
            [1] => 2016-05-06
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-06
            [2] => 3
            [unit] => 3
            [3] => 600
            [value] => 600
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00115
            [splcode] => FGC00115
            [1] => 2016-05-10
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-10
            [2] => 476
            [unit] => 476
            [3] => 3808
            [value] => 3808
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00062
            [splcode] => FGC00062
            [1] => 2016-05-25
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-25
            [2] => 10
            [unit] => 10
            [3] => 80
            [value] => 80
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00059
            [splcode] => FGC00059
            [1] => 2016-05-30
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-30
            [2] => 50
            [unit] => 50
            [3] => 400
            [value] => 400
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => FGC00117
            [splcode] => FGC00117
            [1] => 2016-05-31
            [tran_date] => 2016-05-31
            [2] => 50
            [unit] => 50
            [3] => 400
            [value] => 400
        )

)
```

Comment: use foreach loop and make new array

Comment: plz post a demo code for HINT

Comment: You need to clear more what you want??? From the scratch i suggest to use foreach..

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach and in_array to solve your issue as below.

```
$tempArray = $outArray = array();
$count = 1;

foreach($yourArray as $aKey=>$aVal){
    if (in_array($aVal['splcode'], $aVal)){
        //do something
        continue; // it will skip the current loop if the condition satisfies
    }
    $outArray[$count] = $aVal;
    $tempArray[] = $aVal['splcode'];
    $count++;
}
//You will get the result in the variable $outArray
unset($tempArray); // clear the temp array
```

Comment: I like your inline comments, shouldn't be $count initialized as zero?

Comment: @vivoconunxino, No issues. We can use $count as zero if required.

Answer (score -1):

The array_unique function will do this for you. You just needed to add the SORT_REGULAR flag:

$items_thread = array_unique($items_thread, SORT_REGULAR);

Comment: It won't work in this case, as the values are different (despite they share the same id)